# When to release/autorelease VC's that will be pushed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

I have come across previous problems which occur when I release a viewController after pushing it via the UINavigationController, so I now autorelease every viewController that will be pushed. But I often see code where the developer releases the viewController after pushing it.

My question is, when is the correct time to release/autorelease a UIViewController when pushed onto the stack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push

release

The navigation controller retains the view controller when you push it.

I would suggest any of your previous problems were nothing to do with the above process, but elsewhere.

Comment: But the problem I was coming across is a exc_bad_access when releasing the v/c after pushing.

Comment: If you could show a code block that reproduced this then we could help with that individual issue. I highly doubt it's to do with the process as listed in my answer.

Comment: I am not currently getting the problem, but I will post if I do.

Comment: The EXC_BAD_ACCESS might have had something to do with an object IN the VC, but not the VC itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewController *yourViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
[yourViewController release];`

Answer (score 0):

Whether you autorelease the view controller before the push or release the view controller after the push makes little difference.  The release after the push is a bit more efficient since it would cause the view controller to be released sooner (freeing up memory faster) but the autorelease will also release it soon, but a bit later.